# What is the proper method to stop/exit a node.js route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node.js / express route that firstly checks if a cookie is set or not.

This works well, now i want to exit the route if no cookie is set.

My route lookes like this

```
app.post('/VerEmpresas', function(req, res) {


  if(req.cookies.cookieName1) {
    var cookie = JSON.parse(req.cookies.cookieName1);

    if (!cookie || cookie.codigo != 0) {
      console.log('error' + cookie.codigo);
    } 

    if (cookie && cookie.codigo == 0) {
      console.log('ok' + cookie.codigo);
    } 
  } else {

    console.log('no cookie');
  }


});
```

I assume i can replace the console.log('ok') with my usual task like a knex() database call and let the res.send resolve in there.

Is there a proper way to excape the route if there is no cookie so that code after will not be executed?

Comment: Simply `return`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Simple return would suffice the requirement here. However I want to point out that one should have a middleware for cookie check. Second, one should return proper status like res.status(401).send('Unauthorized access')

Comment: Keeping a middleware will give you a cleaner way to exit if no cookie found

Comment: @binariedMe thanks for commenting, what middleware you suggest?

Comment: express has middleware feature inbuilt which you can find here : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: @IngolfKrauss You can follow the answer I just posted which might give a better picture of what should be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the else part, you just send the error response.  Or `return`

```
if (req.cookies.cookieName1) {
  var cookie = JSON.parse(req.cookies.cookieName1);
  if (!cookie || cookie.codigo != 0) {
    console.log('error' + cookie.codigo);
  }
  if (cookie && cookie.codigo == 0) {
    console.log('ok' + cookie.codigo);
  }
} else {
  res.status(401).send('error, no cookie'); // or return
  console.log('no cookie');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to do session checks or similar stuff, you might want to consider utilizing express's middleware. Because you may want to add same check for other routes as well where you need to have session.

For the code above, you can try something like this :

```
function checkCookie (req, res, next) {
  if(req.cookies.cookieName1) {
    var cookie = JSON.parse(req.cookies.cookieName1);
    if (cookie && cookie.codigo == 0) {
      next();
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send('error' + cookie.codigo);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(401).send('no cookie');
  }

})


app.post('/VerEmpresas', checkCookie, function(req, res) {
   // Implement your business logic here in place of console.log('ok');
});

//If you want this middleware for all the routes
//You can use the function like this app.use(checkCookie);
```

In the above code you can see that, in case cookie is found and is valid, we are calling next instead of sending the response, which means it will go to next task in the route pipeline.

Comment: thanks for this answer, in case i wanted to use it for all my routes, do i have to write all my routes as app.post('/VerEmpresas', checkCookie, function(req, res) {});, when i declare app.use(checkCookie);? thanks for helping

Comment: You can either use app.use or put middleware in each route. The problem is if you use app.use(checkCookie), you are applying cookie check for even login route which is supposed to be free. You can however use app.use('/api/', checkCookie), you can have cookie check only for routes starting with 'api' and keep all auth based route with pattern '/api/*'.